# How to have slidejs animate to a specific slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind a click event to this HTML element,

```
<span class="section-link">FINANCIAL AID »</span>
```

The jQuery event I intend to use is this,

```
$('.section-link').bind('click', function() {
  //animate to the second slide
});
```

This click event I am binding is intended on leveraging slidejs to animate to the second slide.

SlideJS default usage is the following code on .ready,

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
   start: 2
  });
});
```

Any JS/jQuery developers have suggestions on how to do that?

For more info on the framework I am using visit, http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: SlidesJS doesn't seem to have much of an API. You may want to avoid having to write a bunch of custom code by using bxSlider or Bootstrap's carousel instead.

Comment: Agreed. I tried doing custom code first and it was definitely a rabbit hole not worth pursuing. Leveraged Bootstrap out of box and just called carousel methods when needed. Turned out to be easier (obviously). Roughly 2 hours to prototype versus 1.5 days stressing about the former. Thanks @isherwood

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.section-link').on('click', function() {
  slides.moveTo(2);
});
```

Or, it looks like you can enable pagination...

```
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    pagination: {
      active: true,
        // [boolean] Create pagination items.
        // You cannot use your own pagination. Sorry.
      effect: "slide"
        // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
    }
  });
});
```

And then just do:

```
<a href="#2">My link</a>
```